Trace theorem for unbounded domain
The trace theorem for bounded domain says there exists a continuous operator $T : W^{1,p}(\Omega) \to L^{p}(\partial \Omega)$ such that $Tu = u|_{\partial \Omega}$ if $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$. I would like to know if there is any equivalent theorem for unbounded domain under some suitable hypothesis, or for any open set with regular boundary.

Such a result can be found in the classical reference: Adams: Sobolev spaces.
See Section V.1. No boundedness of the domain is needed. For domains with unbounded boundary one needs some kind of uniform boundedness of boundary parametrizations.
